# Remove commodity from cart if customer does not start checkout within after 20 minutes

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, automation

So my shop is going to sell entry Tickets of all kind.
How can I reserve the Ticket for 20 minutes and then remove it if the customer did not start a checkout?

Comment: Run a batch process to disable the products, hope you have a good server as you need to do it via the API.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to do this?  Presumably you will have a limited stock of the tickets.  By adding the product to the cart, the stock for that product is not altered or 'reserved' in any way, this only happens when you actually make the purchase.  This means others can continue to purchase tickets and if the product is then out of stock when the customer comes to checkout, they will be informed of that and will not be able to checkout themselves.

Comment: Yes I need this as some tickets are bind to a entry time and some customers put the ticket in the cart 30 minutes before the selected entry time. So i need to remove the tickets quite a time before the selected entry time. Otherwise they might take to long and checkout with an selected entry time in the past. And this would bring A LOT of problems. So removing the Tickets early enough is what we want to go for.

Comment: Ok, well it's up to you how you work it but from how you have described things so far it doesn't sound like just removing the product from the cart is going to be anything like a complete solution...

Comment: I already have the rest of the solution. This question is the missing part to the hole solution. In the meanwhile i found this: https://store.plumrocket.com/magento-extensions/cart-reservation-magento-extension.html With this plugin I should be able to achive the needed removals. I'm gonna give this a try and answer if it works out.

Comment: Have a look at `Mage_Checkout_CartController` and `deleteAction()`.  It's a very short method showing how to remove a product from the cart.